# I ejected Bootable SSD from ubuntu UI accidentally, oops?

Tags: linux, ssd, eject

I was trying eject the USB stick drive from my Linux machine, when I accidentally clicked on wrong drive and ended up ejecting the SSD drive. Now that SSD also happens to the bootable SSD With stored data.
After doing that I am not able to access file system icin. If I click on that drive from ubuntu UI, nothing happens.

I haven't rebooted the machine since and I am able to view the data from the terminal shell.

If I plug in another USB stick , it gets recognized but can't access that either.

Is there a graceful way to come out of this situation without loosing data or without rebooting the machine ?
Is there a graceful 'undo' command that I can use ?

Answer (score 1):

If you used the interface to gracefully "eject" the device, it should have been gracefully unmounted, which means nothing more will have been written to it.  If it was your boot partition, your system should reboot normally.  If the partition also included `/bin`, that would explain why you cannot mount new devices, as `/bin/mount` is also no longer present, having been contained in the unmounted filesystem.

In short, you should be fine rebooting in your current state.